# What to do when I have an answer to post but the question is closed as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, answers, locked-posts

I've just spent a long time meticulously crafting a model answer to a question on SO, that I was quite proud of, it's nice to give back. By the time I pressed "post" the question was marked as a duplicate and my generous attempt to share my knowledge is thwarted..

Just because information already exists doesn't mean to say that new information hasn't emerged, or that my answer is even addressing the same point that made it considered a duplicate.

But more then anything, this is beyond frustrating! I doubt I will be answering any more questions for a while. If I have helpful information that I think is useful to someone who asked a question, but that question has been closed as a duplicate, what can I do to still make my answer available?

Comment: Have you thought about adding your answer to the duplicate question?  Also, I don't see a `feature-request` in this post...maybe I'm missing it.  What exactly do you want to discuss in this?  It seems like a rant/complaint more than a discussion post.

Comment: Or, if the question is not a duplicate then editing the question to make this fact clear? Thereby, hopefully, getting the question re-opened and your answer posted.

Comment: *"But more then anything, this is beyond frustrating! "* but what's possibly more frustrating is seeing a bunch of duplicate answers because you didn't get the CV through in time. I feel your pain.

Answer (score 6):

As has been suggested in the comments - you've essentially got two scenarios: if your answer is relevant to the linked duplicate, or if it isn't. If your answer is applicable to the question marked as the existing duplicate, then post it there! That's the point of linking it - to point to the better version of essentially the same question. If, though, you feel like what you've written isn't relevant to the linked question, then you've got to decide why that is. Is it because you've picked up on something in this new question that those who marked it a duplicate overlooked, meaning it's really a different question? If that's the case, then you should edit the question to make that clear and ideally get it reopened. If, though, it's not relevant simply because your answer is extremely localized to this specific question and the one it's marked as a duplicate of is a more general case, then you may just have to recognize that your work isn't likely to help others in the future. Without knowing the specifics of the questions you're talking about, it's hard to say which case it may be.

Comment: How did I answer this question after it was already put on hold? Odd.

Comment: The system wanted to give you an opportunity to rub salt in OP's wound.

Comment: Hey now, I was sincerely trying to advise OP on constructive ways to react to their situation! Honestly though, I feel like there's an implied question here that OP just failed to communicate clearly -- "What can I do when I feel like I have new information to offer that's relevant specifically to helping the OP of a question marked as a duplicate?"

Comment: Especially since this was originally tagged with [tag:feature-request], it seems clear that OP intended to be asking for a way to make their answer available but just didn't get that across well.

Comment: @sphanley BoltClock was just teasing you.  Your answer is fine.

Comment: @servy I know - I'm more just surprised that this question was squashed so fast, rather than anyone trying to encourage someone who clearly came here initially to do their best to make a positive contribution. I feel like the atmosphere here could have been a bit more welcoming despite the OP's mistake in tone and emphasis.